# how to use nuget package in xamarin shared project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working with xamarin potable project and I made it like this -
[here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mystorage-ded50.appspot.com/o/Capture.jpg?alt=media&token=7ce515ca-a8ed-425a-8cb0-d618bbb2ca05).
And I'd like to use couchbase lite sdk 1.4 (current version) in the project.
But I can't add the nuget package in potable and UWP project.
Someone says current version dosn't support UWP and I will be a standard library in version 2.0.
So I'd like to make WPF project instead of UWP.
But I need to keeps the structure of xamarin potable project.
So when 2.0 version will be release, I need to make UWP project.
But I can't add the nuget package to potable project for now.
So I can't implement shared logic.
Who knows how to make the shared project that include wpf project similar xamarin potable project .
I implemented MVVM to current project.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-training-todo
This is shared project that used couchbase lite sdk.